# Redhat httpd start failed showing "ELinks: Connection refused"

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, ssl, certificates

I'm on RHEL 6.5 and Apache 2.2.15. And now applying a trusted SSL on the Server. After adding the respective SSL related Certs and files, my `Apache` is NOT starting up anymore.

Here are some outputs:

```
# apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
# service httpd fullstatus
ELinks: Connection refused
# service httpd start
Starting httpd:                    [FAILED]
# tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Mon Aug 04 17:57:08 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Aug 04 17:57:41 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Aug 04 18:03:31 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Aug 04 18:06:27 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

And when I do `# tail /var/log/messages`, there's no errors related to Apache or this operations.

What seems to be the problem, please? I have already turned off `iptables` and `SELinux`.

Comment: Are the certificate files readable by the `apache` user?

Comment: In addition to @CristianCiupitu's suggestion. Do the certificates have the correct SELinux contexts?  Maybe run the server with SELinux disabled to see if it helps narrow down the issue.

Comment: @garethTheRed: "I have already turned off [...] SELinux".

Comment: Hi @CristianCiupitu, those files need to be readable by apache? That means should give "r" to group. Is it supposed secure?

Comment: And hi @garethTheRed as i mentioned above, SELINUX is already disabled (and even rebooted)

Comment: The certificates are supposed to be read by the web server. Otherwise how can it use them? Anyway, try giving it reading permissions and see if it starts.

Comment: You might also want to increase the verbosity of error messages by setting `OPTIONS="-e info"` or `OPTIONS="-e debug"` in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` ([httpd docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html#options)).

Comment: hi @CristianCiupitu yea now i have given `644` to those files. But still failing. Now it is showing `[debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module ssl_module [FAILED]` .. after enabling the debug logs.

Comment: Have you checked the whole path to the files i.e. directories?

Comment: Yes i did. All correct. But the `ssl_module` is keep failing.

Answer (score 1):

`service apache fullstatus` is an alias for `/usr/sbin/apachectl fullstatus`. From the manual of apachectl:

> fullstatus
>
> Displays a full status report from mod_status. For this to work, you need to have mod_status enabled on your server and a
>   text-based browser such as lynx available on your system. The URL used
>   to access the status report can be set by editing the STATUSURL
>   variable in  the script.

It makes sense that fullstatus says the connection is refused: your apache is not running.

This fullstatus is not the reason something is wrong, it is just a symptom of apache not running.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue today. This is how I fixed the issue

```
~#cat /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid 
2322
~#ps aux |grep 2322
root   2322  0.0  0.0 81272 3396 ? Ss   Nov23 0:02 /usr/libexec/postfix/master
~#service postfix stop
Shutting down postfix:
~#/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart
httpd not running, trying to start
~#netstat -nlp |grep 80
tcp        0      0 :::80    :::*                        LISTEN      14549/httpd
~#service postfix start
Starting postfix:                                          [  OK  ]
```